# Prove that $ \nabla c(-2x^T Dc + c^Tc) = 0$

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives, vector-analysis

I'm trying to solve the equation:

$\nabla c(-2x^T Dc + c^Tc) = 0$

where:

$\nabla c$ represents the gradient with respect to $c$,
$x$ is a row vector,
$D$ is a matrix,
$c$ is a vector.

In my solving process, I encountered a difficulty in the partial derivative with respect to $c$ of the term $-2x^T Dc$, which seems to become $-2D^Tx$. I don't fully understand how this expression is derived.

Could you kindly explain the step or provide some guidance on how to obtain this specific partial derivative? I appreciate any help or clarification you can provide.

Thank you very much!

Comment: The Frechet derivative of $-2x^TDc$ is $-2x^TD$, so the gradient is the transpose $-2D^Tx$.

Answer (score 1):

$x^\top D c$ can be written explicitly as $\sum_i \sum_j D_{ij} x_i c_j$.

The partial derivative with respect to $c_k$ is $$\frac{\partial}{\partial c_k} \sum_i \sum_j D_{ij} x_i c_j = \sum_i D_{ik} x_k.$$

The gradient with respect to the vector $c$ is a vector containing the partial derivatives with respect to $c_k$, i.e.
$$\nabla_c \sum_i \sum_j D_{ij} x_i c_j = \begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial}{\partial c_1} \sum_i \sum_j D_{ij} x_i c_j
\\
\vdots
\\
\frac{\partial}{\partial c_n} \sum_i \sum_j D_{ij} x_i c_j
\end{bmatrix}
= \begin{bmatrix}
\sum_i D_{i1} x_i
\\
\vdots
\\
\sum_i D_{in} x_i
\end{bmatrix}
= D^\top x.
$$